# I want to print any text without using Print function in java?

Tags: java

I want to print any text without using system.out.println() in java? It is possible If yes
then how; Any idea.

Comment: By "print" do you mean printing to paper? Or writing to the console? In the latter case why would you not want to use the methods disgned for this purpose?

Comment: In more general terms: Don't tell us "but not X" without telling us why X is unsuitable. It makes it really hard to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   System.out.write("text".getBytes());

   System.out.format("%s", "text");
```

Comment: ok, thanks Thilo I am using this its work when I use try and catch.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually possible and there is an awesome method to do it

make a class, call it `so`

make it like this

```
public class so
{
    public static void p(Object o){
        System.out.print(o);
    }
    public static void pln(Object o){
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

then call the method like

```
so.pln("hi");
```

or

```
so.p("hi");
```

you can actually use it like an ordinary `print` or `println` function just writing lesser...

if you just done want to use `println` use `print`

like this

```
System.out.print("\n whatever you want");
```

`\n` takes it to the next line.........

Or what you can do is using your IDE go to the `println` function and do whatever is done in there.........

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` in a `PrintStream` which is a kind of `OutputStream`. You can send raw bytes on that stream, if you wish it so. This is not recommended, because how raw bytes are handled depends on the host system and its configuration (the dreadful "locale" business). The `print()` and `println()` methods do "the right thing" for you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? Are you looking for [log4j](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) logging?

Answer (score -1):

System.out.logd("text") is pretty similar. If it's just the specific call you can't use or something.

Comment: My System.out does not have logd. What does it do?

Comment: There is no such thing as "System.out.logd"